# Use Jenkins to Write a Dockerfile and push to Git repo?

Tags: git, jenkins, dockerfile

We're using an external Jenkins server for CI and need to figure out how to create a Dockerfile and then push this Dockerfile to a Git repository. Please help.

Also, we would need the build number injected into the body of the text of the Dockerfile as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide a bit more context on it: there are too many buzzwords around too little beef to work with.

Comment: We're building on Jenkins and then deploying on Red Hat OpenShift version 3. We're currently using a plugin for Jenkins to place the build artifacts in a company repository, and then on Openshift we're running a Dockerfile that pulls the artifact from the repo. The problem is trying to dynamically grab the latest artifact from the repo. A proposed solution was to use Jenkins to create the Dockerfile since Jenkins has access to the build number environment variable, but I have not figured out how to make this Dockerfile with Jenkins yet.